Is there a term for this relationship between DAGs?
Consider two DAGs A and B, such that the nodes of B are a subset of those of A, and a path exists between two nodes in B iff a path exists between the same two nodes in A.  B is not, in general, a subgraph of A, because it may have to have edges not in A in order to preserve reachability.  Is there a term for this relationship?

$B$ has to be a subgraph of the "free semicategory" generated by $A$. This doesn't have a name that I'm aware of but then I don't know much about DAGs.
